# Substitute the Lag() function with another similiar option in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

With the help of some of the users here in stackoverflow, I reached to the following query. The problem is that this query works well in SQL Server, but not in Sybase as it doesn't support LAG(). I have been trying to get it to work but no success.

The query is quite complicated but help in subsituting the LAG() function with something similar would be appreciated.

```
SELECT created
    , bname
    , total_share
FROM (
    SELECT TT.created
        , TT.bname
        , TT.total_share
        , lag(TT.total_share) OVER (
            PARTITION BY TT.bname ORDER BY TT.created
            ) AS prev_share
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT t.created AS created
            , t.NAME AS bname
            , t.total_share
        FROM (
            SELECT cast(fsp.created AS VARCHAR(19)) AS created
                , e.NAME
                , e.initials
                , fsp.modified
                , CASE 
                    WHEN cl.price_per_item = 0
                        THEN CAST('' AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
                    ELSE CAST((fsp.new_price / cl.price_per_item * 100) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
                    END AS new_share
                , CASE 
                    WHEN cl.price_per_item = 0
                        THEN CAST('' AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
                    ELSE CAST((prev / cl.price_per_item * 100) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
                    END AS old_share
                , fs.STATE
                , CASE 
                    WHEN fsp.prev_price IS NULL
                        THEN 0
                    ELSE fsp.prev_price
                    END AS prev
                , fsp.new_price AS nprice
                , (prev - nprice) AS diff
                , new_share - old_share AS diff_share
                , old_share + diff_share AS total_share
            FROM project_manager pm
            INNER JOIN dba.project p ON pm.project = p.id
            LEFT JOIN dba.contract c ON p.id = c.project
            LEFT JOIN dba.contract_line cl ON cl.contract = c.id
            LEFT JOIN dba.product pt ON cl.product = pt.id
            LEFT JOIN dba.specified_product sp ON sp.product = pt.id
            LEFT JOIN dba.frozen_sale fs ON fs.spec_product = sp.id
                AND fs.contract = c.id
                AND fs.line = cl.idx
            LEFT JOIN dba.frozen_sale_split fsp ON fsp.frozen_sale = fs.id
                AND fsp.employee = pm.consultant
            LEFT JOIN dba.employee e ON fsp.employee = e.person
            LEFT JOIN dba.person ps ON fsp.creator = ps.id
            WHERE p.id = 50000002735
                AND e.NAME IS NOT NULL
            ) AS t

        ) TT /* here */
    ) x
WHERE (
        prev_share IS NULL
        OR prev_share  total_share
        )
ORDER BY created
    , bname
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the row_number window function to the entire table, and then using a subquery joining on the appropriately lagged row number?

Comment: No, I haven't, quite frankly it's quite advanced for me. I got to the Lag function because of some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is untested, but the approach is to use the row_number window function to assign a sequential number (`rnum` in the code) to each row, ordered by the `created` value.  This is done in the initial CTE.  The main query then joins that CTE to itself, with a join condition of a difference of one in the `rnum` values.

```
 with inp as (
    SELECT TT.created
        , TT.bname
        , TT.total_share
        , row_number over(order by TT.created) as rnum
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT t.created AS created
            , t.NAME AS bname
            , t.total_share
        FROM (
            SELECT cast(fsp.created AS VARCHAR(19)) AS created
                , e.NAME
                , e.initials
                , fsp.modified
                , CASE 
                    WHEN cl.price_per_item = 0
                        THEN CAST('' AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
                    ELSE CAST((fsp.new_price / cl.price_per_item * 100) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
                    END AS new_share
                , CASE 
                    WHEN cl.price_per_item = 0
                        THEN CAST('' AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
                    ELSE CAST((prev / cl.price_per_item * 100) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
                    END AS old_share
                , fs.STATE
                , CASE 
                    WHEN fsp.prev_price IS NULL
                        THEN 0
                    ELSE fsp.prev_price
                    END AS prev
                , fsp.new_price AS nprice
                , (prev - nprice) AS diff
                , new_share - old_share AS diff_share
                , old_share + diff_share AS total_share
            FROM project_manager pm
            INNER JOIN dba.project p ON pm.project = p.id
            LEFT JOIN dba.contract c ON p.id = c.project
            LEFT JOIN dba.contract_line cl ON cl.contract = c.id
            LEFT JOIN dba.product pt ON cl.product = pt.id
            LEFT JOIN dba.specified_product sp ON sp.product = pt.id
            LEFT JOIN dba.frozen_sale fs ON fs.spec_product = sp.id
                AND fs.contract = c.id
                AND fs.line = cl.idx
            LEFT JOIN dba.frozen_sale_split fsp ON fsp.frozen_sale = fs.id
                AND fsp.employee = pm.consultant
            LEFT JOIN dba.employee e ON fsp.employee = e.person
            LEFT JOIN dba.person ps ON fsp.creator = ps.id
            WHERE p.id = 50000002735
                AND e.NAME IS NOT NULL
            ) AS t
        ) TT
    ) 
SELECT
    created
    , bname
    , total_share
    , prev.total_share as prev_share
FROM
    inp
    left join inp as prev on prev.rnum=inp.rnum-1
        and prev.bname=inp.bname
WHERE (
    prev.total_share IS NULL
    OR prev.total_share  total_share
    )
ORDER BY 
    created
    , bname
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help